# Could not find a tree control for the tree

Tags: angular-material

I am facing an error for sample code I am using angular 6 and angular material for application design:

```
<mat-tree>
    <mat-tree-node> parent node </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Error Message:

> Error: Could not find a tree control for the tree

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation on Material Angular is not super clear about it...
You need tho specifie a `[treeControl]="nestedTreeControl"` of the type `NestedTreeControl<FileNode>;`

If you go to [Material Angular Tree Component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) and check the code you will understand easily.

Comment: I never would have figured this out. I've been looking for documentation on the class, does the lack of documentation and only dumping examples suggest that it's too unstable to be considered for a startup? I can use *ngFor with ul/ui and flex box and get a pretty decent tree going that I know will be stable for at least a year or two.

Comment: Too... unstable... for... a startup

Answer (score 5):

In case you really want to work with a flat tree then this error also appears when you accidentally use `<mat-nested-tree-node>` instead of `<mat-tree-node>`.